# C# GUI Creation - What type of Container to use for massive amounts of output text?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm hoping to build a GUI with VS C#. This GUI will continually display (massive amounts of) updated text that you can be scrolled back to view. What container would I use? How would I mitigate against eating up too much memory in the effort? What strategy would be best to do this?

**My Goal:**
To create a panel on my UI that displays all textual information that my application is processing.

*Much like starting a program in unix shell with a verbose command.*

**GUI Type:** Windows Form

**Update Interval:** Random - Although updates happen many times per minute

All updates will be accumulated and visible on the panel (this is what I mean by massive amounts). This will grow over the lifetime of the running application.

Comment: Krshll187 can you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve what is considered `massive amounts of updated text`? there are many ways to store as well as display text

Comment: This question is too open-ended - we'll need a lot more detail, or it will most likely be closed.  Start with: web or desktop app?  If desktop, win forms or WPF?  What does "massive amounts of text" mean?  How often will it be updated?  How?  And so on...

Comment: Your update answers none of the questions I asked.

Comment: Perhaps just write the information out to a file and then just look at the file using some other program that already handles something like this, i.e. notepad++?

Comment: @Servy thats what I was steering towards. I wasnt sure if there was a better way

Comment: @Mrshll187 You certainly *can* do it yourself, and you can probably get better functionality if you wanted to, but it would be a lot of time and effort that you'd spend, and I just don't know if it would be worthwhile.  Doing something like this effectively if you truly have a large amount of text to work with is not easy; it can be done, sure, but you'll be doing a lot of work from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're appending to the contents, then you want to use something like a `DataGridView`, which allows you to append to a mutable collection. The `Text` property of a `TextBox` contains an immutable string, so appending to that is generally inefficient, as it requires constructing a new string object, before GC'ing the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have to display an increasing amount of text (lines which come one by one) I use any kind of lists and not text containers. strings are copied on each operation so the performance is horrible.

On lists (ie ListBox) you can just insert the new items in the beginning or at the end.

In case you want to have the whole text as one you can concatenate the text at the moment of exportation which will happen way less often than an update of the content.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the type of response I was looking for